# how to remove the error shown?

Tags: visual-c++

"ILLEGAL USE OF FLOATING POINT"

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
main()
{
    double a;
    cout<<"Enter a number\n";
    cin>>a;
    for(int j=2;j<=a;j++)
        if(a%j == 0)
        {
            cout<<"Its not a prime number\n";
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            cout<<"Its a prime number\n";
            getch();
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace `double a` with an integer data type like `int` or `long`. You cannot do a [modulus](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) operation (`%`) on floating point numbers (hence the error about illegal use on floating point numbers).

Comment: i tried it with int,long,char but the error still exists.plz help me solve it

Comment: @Numair Siddique: You did replace `double a;` with `long a;` and the error persists ? Hard to believe. On which line exactly does you compiler say is the error ?

Comment: Please read the **How do I ask questions here?** section of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn more about _accepting an answer_.